# Using BETWEEN vs. OR

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am performing a join where I need to grab certain data for a day, if it exists for that day perfect grab it, if not grab the data for the previous day. I am not sure which would be the optimal solution, using `BETWEEN` the date ranges or using `OR`. Here is an example query:

```
INSERT INTO #table2
               SELECT #table1.id, #table1.ordertime,
               A.current as current
               FROM #table1
               LEFT JOIN #exchange as A
               ON #table1.id = A.source
               AND (#table1.ordertime::date = A.begin::date
               OR #table1.ordertime::date = dateadd(d,-1, #A.begin)::date);
```

versus

```
INSERT INTO #table2
               SELECT #table1.id, #table1.ordertime,
               A.current as current
               FROM #table1
               LEFT JOIN #exchange as A
               ON #table1.id = A.source
               AND #table1.ordertime::date BETWEEN A.begin::date AND dateadd(d,-1, #A.begin)::date
```

Comment: Same thing. Matter of taste.

Comment: so there's no performance gain to be had, interesting, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Same thing. BETWEEN looks good :)

Comment: Same bad performance because you compare a field value `#table1.ordertime::date` with a function result `dateadd(d,-1, #A.begin)::date`, forcing a table scan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so what would be a better solution?

Comment: please delete one of your tags as postgresql <> redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution will grab both dates if they exist, possibly inserting more rows that you wanted.

A better approach is to join twice - once for the matching date, and once for the day before, and get the first non-null value:

```
INSERT INTO #table2
   SELECT
       #table1.id
   ,   #table1.ordertime
   ,   COALESCE(A.current, B.current) as current
   FROM #table1
   LEFT JOIN #exchange as A ON #table1.id = A.source AND #table1.ordertime::date = A.begin::date
   LEFT JOIN #exchange as B ON #table1.id = B.source AND #table1.ordertime::date = dateadd(d,-1, #B.begin)::date
```

Now you are guaranteed a single row in `#table2` for each row of `#table1`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use neither.  Instead, use inequalities:

```
AND (#table1.ordertime >= (A.begin - interval '1 day')::date
     #table1.ordertime < (A.begin + interval '1 day')::date
```

By putting all the "functions" and casts on one side, there is hope that an index (if available) could be used for the `join`.

If you are only interested in the date component of `A.begin`, perhaps you want to store the value as a date, with no time component.

Comment: there's no notion of indexes in `Redshift` unfortunately only distribution keys for the nodes, it's a columnar DB

Comment: @eagle . . . I guess I was focusing on the Postgres tag.

Comment: fair enough, yea it does get frustrating not having any indexes